# How to declare various document types in Solr?

Tags: solr, solr4

How can I "replicate" database structure in Solr?

Is the `schema.xml` a represetation of only one *entity* type? Like Car or Costumer, etc?

How can I declare the structure of Car **and** Costumer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a field `type` of the `string` datatype. At index-time, set the value to `car` or `customer`. So if you want to shop for red swifts:

```
q=red+swifts&fq=type:car
```

The solr schema is a giant (and sparsely occupied) table. So if your Db had a `car`s table with 20 columns and 12500 entries and a `customer` table with 30 columns and 12500 entries, your solr core contains 25000 entries with 50 fields. And yes, its efficient given Solr's indexing strategies, even faster than relational DBs.

Answer (score 1):

solr will allow you to index both the entities together if you maintain the fields which both  of Entities have and still query them.
However, if you want to have a relationship with the entities Solr does provide a [Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) feature which though limited (as i had last checked upon) would enable you to query with relationship. Check for the Join further and you would find new developments in it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Solr is a kind of Nosql, which is different from RDBMS. In RDBMS, tables are in relationship, you can perform join action to join them together, or get data from view. But in solr, you can not perform join action at all. One solr query can only be executed on one core. So you can't replicate strcture from RDBMS simply and you must redesign your schema for solr.